# How to grant airflow access to create data in Google Cloud Storage Bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I have created a DAG that exports MySQL data to a Google Cloud Storage Bucket.

I got the following error that I don't have access to create the .json file from airflow.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/**init**.py", line 41, in autodetect
>       from . import file_cache
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 41, in 
>       'file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0')
>
> ImportError: file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0
>   [2018-01-10 16:18:52,584] {discovery.py:274} INFO - URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/storage/v1/rest
>
> [2018-01-10 16:18:52,585] {transport.py:157} INFO - Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
>
> [2018-01-10 16:18:52,661] {client.py:777} INFO - Refreshing access_token
>
> [2018-01-10 16:18:53,698] {_helpers.py:132} WARNING - **init**() takes at most 2 positional arguments (3 given)
>
> [2018-01-10 16:18:53,712] {discovery.py:872} INFO - URL being requested: POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/podio-reader-storage/o?uploadType=media&alt=json&name=phones_schema.json
>
> [2018-01-10 16:18:54,936] {http.py:120} WARNING - Encountered 403 Forbidden with reason "forbidden"
>
> [2018-01-10 16:18:54,936] {models.py:1417} ERROR - https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/podio-reader-storage/o?uploadType=media&alt=json&name=phones_schema.json returned "podio-reader-service1-717@podio-data.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.create access to podio-reader-storage/phones_schema.json.">

My airflow connection to Google Cloud Platform is:
[image]

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by allowing my credential key full control access to Cloud Storage